# Como percorrer dados de um arquivo htm?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso percorrer os dados de um `.htm` que está zipado nesse [arquivo.zip](http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_lotfac.zip) para poder pegar a data, números sorteados e quantidade de ganhadores. Mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso de uma forma automatizada. Alguém pode me dizer qual ferramenta ou tecnologia usar para se conseguir percorrer esse arquivo?

Comment: Tente ver o [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)